# Why can't I download a Kaggle dataset directly to my Google Drive using Colab?

Tags: dataset, cloud, google-colaboratory, kaggle, drive

As I am currently trying to work with large amounts of data (500GB) from a Kaggle competition, I want to download it directly to my Google Drive and work on it through Colab. To do this, I increased my Google Drive storage to 2TB yesterday and used the following code:

```
# mount my Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

#Connect to Kaggle API
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "..." # username from the api key
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "..." # key from the api key

# change working directory
%cd drive/MyDrive/Kaggle/Google_Contrails

# download dataset
!kaggle competitions download -c google-research-identify-contrails-reduce-global-warming
```

The download starts immediately and actually loads into the correct directory (it is displayed in the correct folder on the left in Colab). But no matter what I try, after about 200GB, I get the following error message: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device.
Why doesn't my colab recognize my 2TB memory? Before mounting my drive, colab shows 195GB disk space and after in shows only 200GB. But when I go to Google Drive website, it already made my upgrade to 2TB.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

(I tried not changing the working directory and instead using:
!kaggle competitions download -c google-research-identify-contrails-reduce-global-warming -p /content/drive/MyDrive/Kaggle/Google_Contrails

-> Same problem )